# Serialization of an object with foreign key into json

Tags: django

this is in Django:

```
data = []
data += serializers.serialize("json", conversation_deal)
data += serializers.serialize("json", deal_statuses)
dat = serializers.serialize("json", data)
return HttpResponse(dat)
```

I would like to save one round trip to the webservice and combine two jsons into one.
What I tried to do was to serialize each object into json and add them into an array and serialize them again as json.  But it throws an exception.

I also tried to put the two python objects into the array and serialize them all into json, which also failed.

How is this usually done?

**Update:**

Exception:

```
str: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

**Update 2:**

I have some more information, and it seems its somehow Django related the way it serializes the objects.

the following works perfectly fine:

```
deal_statuses = DealStatus.objects.all()        
data = serializers.serialize("json", deal_statuses)
return HttpResponse(data)
```

but this fails..

```
conversation_deal = Conversation_Deal.objects.filter(conversation_id__in=call_id)
data = serializers.serialize("json", conversation_deal)
return HttpResponse(data)
```

This is how Conversation_Deal is modelled:

```
class Conversation_Deal(models.Model):
    conversation        = models.ForeignKey('Conversation')
    deal                = models.ForeignKey('Deal')
    status              = models.ForeignKey(DealStatus, null=True, blank=True)
```

I found something related to inherited classes [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/) pointing this out why...Even though I am not inheriting, but the same process worked in my case. Hope this helps someone else. I will post this as an answer soon.

Comment: You'll get much better help if you show the exception (and traceback) that you got.

Comment: What do you mean by "failed"?  The serialization, or the call to the webservice?  If the latter, you'll need to provide more info on the service; it may be that it just doesn't support the kind of call you are trying to make.

Comment: @Kave: that's not an actual exception, and it certainly isn't a full traceback.  Truly, more actual information will help.

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to this. I am making the call to my server through jQuery. And it seems any exceptions are swallowed. I am using Aptana Studio in debugging mode. ALl I could figure out that right after `dat = serializers.serialize("json", data)` it throws an exception.  I am trying to figure out if I could somehow get the full traceback. :(

Comment: Try visiting view's url manually. Before that make sure that DEBUG=True in django settings. There will be full traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

Literally since Conversation_Deal has a foreignkey to DealStatus class. It needs to know about it during serialization.

```
all = list(Conversation_Deal.objects.filter(conversation_id__in=call_id)) + list(DealStatus.objects.all())
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(to_json), mimetype='application/json')
```

Hope this helps somebody else.